# REST vs SOAP C# Requester

Tags: c#, rest, soap

I have read a lot of articles that say that the RESTfull services should be faster than SOAP services.
I tried to test this claim by creating two RESTFull servies: `RESTCaller` and `RESTCalled` and another two ASMX services: `SOAPCaller` and `SOAPCalled`.
The idea is that `RESTCaller` sends `iCount` requests to `RESTCalled` and returns the total execution time `RESTResponseTime`, and `SOAPCaller` sends the same `iCount` requests to `SOAPCalled` and returns the total exection time `SOAPResponseTime`.

Notice that the four services are on my local machine.

Unexpectedly, `SOAPResponseTime` is a bit less than `RESTResponseTime`.

Is there any clue of the reason of this unexpected results?

Comment: Did you use WCF, Web API or a custom way to develop your REST Service ?

Comment: I used Web API  to develop them.

Comment: Did you use the classic or core version ?

Comment: this could be due to the stack used by Web API. ASMX is quite an old fashion to develop SOAP Service you should rether use the WCF framework, which is more flexible.

Comment: Okay I'll try to use WCF instead of the Web API and retry.

Comment: But WCF will certainly have lower performance than ASMX. If you develop both the client and the service (full .Net), with WCF, you will be able to use netTcpTransport with binaryEncoding (instead of SOAP encoding). You should have better performances.

Comment: I think i got confused. 
should I try to develop the REST or the SOAP service using WCF?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120119/discussion-between-rom-eh-and-heba-gomaah).

Answer (score 0):

If you are focusing on which approach is "faster", you're focusing on the wrong features that differentiate REST from SOAP.  REST and SOAP are two different philosophies (though, SOAP is really more an example of the RPC philosophy than a philosophy of its own).  They are generally not interchangeable.  Your application design will be heavily influenced by which approach you choose to follow. For any non-trivial application, your performance is going to depend on your back-end code, not whether you use REST or SOAP.

Do not let the results of these tests be the deciding factor on which way you choose to go.